# Typescript: declare variable with same type as another

Tags: typescript

Is there any way to declare a variable with the type of another variable?  For instance, I declare a class member with some type, and then later I want to declare another variable in a function of the same type.  But I don't want to modify the original declaration, and don't want to duplicate it.  It seems like you should be able to do something like:

```
class Foo {
    bar: {[key: string]: string[]};

    func() {
        const x: TypeOf<Foo.bar> = {};
        ....
    }
}
```

I've heard of something like this specifically for return types of functions, but I can't find it anymore...

Comment: You can write `const x: Foo["bar"] = ...` to determine the type.

Comment: [Similar](/q/35546421) [questions](/q/36311284) provide further context.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `typeof` but in class you should get to property:

```
class Foo {
    bar: {[key: string]: string[]};

    func() {
        const x: typeof Foo.prototype.bar = {};
        // here x has type `{[key: string]: string[]}`
    }
}
```

And another example outside of class:

```
class A {
    b: string = ''
}

type test = typeof A.prototype.b // type is `string`
```

[PlayGround](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0G8BQ1XQEYC5oQC4CcBLAOwHNoBeaAcmqQF8klcBPABwFNpcO9Lv2HAPYAzOADo2+IbhmDx6JqEgwAYkKGIUadGHzYEAbQDWHFtjxEyAXQsESpQ9foBuJmmgiArsWAAKAEotDw9gIWI+AA9sVk5RaHUhSWlZWI4FPX4EV21URnogA)

Comment: consider `typeof this['b']`

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```js
class Foo {
    bar: {[key: string]: string[]};

    func() {
        const x: Foo['bar'];
    }
}
```

It's called indexed access

More: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html#handbook-content